# Need to scroll LongListSelector horizontally inside a pivotItem?

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I want to scroll the LongListSelector Horizontally. This LongListSelector is inside a PivotItem.

I tried to put LongListSelector inside a scrollviewer, but not worked.

```
           <ScrollViewer  Width="800" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                    <phone:LongListSelector Name="AllImagesList" LayoutMode="Grid"  GridCellSize="220,230" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding PhotoCollection}"
                                DataContext="{StaticResource viewModel}"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImagesItemTemplate}" 
                                SelectionChanged="onImageListSelectionChanged" />

                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>

        </controls:PivotItem>
```

Is it possible to scroll a LongListSelector Horizontally?

If yes, Please help me , How?

Comment: While it is, your user is going to have a very difficult time trying to get the OS to understand the meaning of that gesture inside a Pivot... This is a pretty bad UX.

Comment: it will give irritation to the users. better you try keep vertical view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting something that scrolls horizontally inside a `Pivot` control is a bad idea.

The `Pivot` control will be trying to detect horizontal swipe gestures and so these would be competing with your `ScrollViewer`. How would the framework know which item you wanted to react to the swipe? How would the person using the app know if their swipe gesture would scroll the list or change the selected pivot item?
There is a reason this doesn't work.

As an alternative, if appropriate, you may want to consider using a `Panorama` control instead as this can have items that are wider than the screen and so support some level of horizontal scrolling. This can't be combined with a vertically scrolling list well though.

A better approach would probably be to reconsider the design of this page.